# Module federation prefetch during browser idle time

Tags: lazy-loading, prefetch, code-splitting, webpack-module-federation

Requirement: To prefetch the remote modules(module federated) during browser idle time in react.

I've tried webpack magic comment `webpackPrefetch: true` but that did not work with module federation. I came across the [post](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/16079) which says webpack magic comments do no work with module federation. Is there any library or any workaround to prefetch the remote modules during browser idle time

I've also tried npm libraries like [@loadable/component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loadable/component?activeTab=readme) which preloads the remote modules, but this is not during the idle time of browser. I am looking for something that does same thing as `webpackPrefetch: true` for module federation.

Comment: I have also been looking for a solution to eagerly import a dynamic remote exposed module. If you use ExternalRemotesPlugin you will load all declared remotes in the config eagerly. In my case I just want specific remotes to have this behavior